# Is it like reThrowing the same exception?

Tags: java, exception

When i executed this code i got "finally"

```
public class Tester {
    static void method() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        try {
            method();
        } catch (Throwable th) { 
            try {
                new Exception();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print("Exception");
            } finally {
                System.out.print("finally");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Unable to figure out the flow of execution!!**

Comment: What confusion do you have in above code?

Comment: i wasn't confused instead i skipped `new Exception();` thinking that the Exception was actually thrown. @RamanSahasi

Comment: No Problem, confusion is part of programming. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of above mentioned code will be

```
finally
```

If you're wondering why the output isn't

```
Exception finally
```

then it is because in the following line of code

```
try {
        new Exception();
    }
```

you're only declaring a new `Exception` object, you're not really throwing it.

if you want the output to be `Exception finally` then you have to throw that object by putting `throw new Exception();` instead of `new Exception();`

The code would then look like:

```
public class HelloWorld{
    static void method() throws Exception{ throw new Exception(); }

    public static void main(String... args){
        try{method();}
        catch(Throwable th)
        {
            try{ throw new Exception(); }
            catch(Exception e){System.out.print("Exception");}
            finally{System.out.print("finally");}    
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Exceptionfinally
```

Answer (score 0):

The `finally` block will be executed if there is or not exception thrown in the code `try` block.